# Why long-lived grpc streaming restarts slowly in a loop

Tags: c++, linux, grpc, grpc-c++

I'm trying to implement an idea described in this [blog post](https://dev.bitolog.com/grpc-long-lived-streaming/).

I'm using long-lived grpc streaming for sending notifications from a backend (server) to applications. A client subscribes for particular notifications and then the server sends them back to the client. When some backend event occurs, clients receive an immediate notification on that event. This rpc will be active while the client is running, because `Finish()` is never called on a backend side. The backend and all clients are running on a same machine, so network latency is not an issue.

To implement the ability to run the client when the backend is not yet running, I'm trying to subscribe the client every 0.5 seconds in a loop:

```cpp
std::string server_addr = "unix-abstract:test";
auto client = MakeClient(server_addr);

while (!TryToSubscribeNotifications(client));
```

If subscription was successful then break; If not, try again.

```cpp
bool
TryToSubscribeNotifications(Client &client)
{
using std::chrono_literals::operator""ms;

std::thread(&Client::SubscribeNotifications, &client).detach();
std::this_thread::sleep_for(500ms);

return client.IsSubscribed();
}
```

Inside `Client` I'm using `atomic_bool` to set and check subscription status. `IsSubscribed()` returns this status.

**The question is:**
Why doesn't the client subscribe for notifications immediately when the backend starts, but only after some random time (usually up to 30 sec) if the client was started about one minute before backend?

Steps to reproduce:

1. run only client, but not backend;
2. wait for one minute. The client should repeatedly print "Notification rpc failed. Attempt #" every 0.5 seconds;
3. run backend;
4. the client should still fail to establish a connection for some random time (usually up to 30 sec).

I'm using grpc [callback-based asynchronous API](https://github.com/grpc/proposal/blob/master/L67-cpp-callback-api.md).

Full repo with code example and build instructions: https://github.com/illukin/grpc-longlive-example

Fedora 36
gcc 12.2.1
protobuf 3.21.6.0
gRPC 1.49.1

Comment: hi!) do you have any ideas? i have the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77025432/grpc-connection-lag

Comment: Sadly, no. And gRPC team members are still silent (https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/mcolnVNpJKs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
List<ChannelOption> channelOptions = new List<ChannelOption>
{
    new ChannelOption("grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms", 1000),
    new ChannelOption("grpc.max_reconnect_backoff_ms", 1000)
};

channel = new Channel(host, port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure, channelOptions);
client = new Commands.CommandsClient(channel);
```

Answer (score 0):

@cerberus, thanks a lot, it works!

C++ solution:

```cpp
Client
MakeClient(std::string &target)
{
  grpc::ChannelArguments chan_args;
  chan_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_INITIAL_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 1000);
  chan_args.SetInt(GRPC_ARG_MAX_RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS, 1000);

  return { grpc::CreateCustomChannel(target, grpc::InsecureChannelCredentials(),
    chan_args)};
}
```