# gRPC connection lag

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-4.8

i get a simple gRPC example from the internet and put it in a loop. i started client BEFORE server. wait about 1 minute. then start server. and client is still getting rpcExceptions for about 30 sec. then it prints replies from the server.

so the question is WHY i have such a delay and how to prevent it?

client code:

```
internal class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    Channel channel = new Channel("localhost", 50000, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
    var client = new GRPCConsoleClient.Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);

    while (true) {
      try {
        var reply = client.SayHello(new GRPCConsoleClient.HelloRequest {
          Name = "asdsad"
        });
        Console.WriteLine(reply);
      } catch (Exception ex) {

      }

      Task t = Task.Delay(1000);
      t.Wait();
    }
  }
}
```

service code:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
  Server server = new Server {
    Services = {
        BindService(new GreeterService())
      },
      Ports = {
        new ServerPort("localhost", 50000, ServerCredentials.Insecure)
      }
  };

  server.Start();

  Console.WriteLine("Greeter server listening on port " + 50000);
  Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop the server...");
  Console.ReadKey();

  server.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
}
```

the more i run the client without a server, the greater the delay

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to poll if a server is available or not is to configure a [retry policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/retries?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configure-a-grpc-retry-policy) for the gRPC channel, as described in the Microsoft documentation:

```cs
var defaultMethodConfig = new MethodConfig
{
    Names = { MethodName.Default },
    RetryPolicy = new RetryPolicy
    {
        MaxAttempts = 5,
        InitialBackoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        MaxBackoff = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        BackoffMultiplier = 1.5,
        RetryableStatusCodes = { StatusCode.Unavailable }
    }
};

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:50000", new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    ServiceConfig = new ServiceConfig { MethodConfigs = { defaultMethodConfig } }
});
```

This policy instructs clients to automatically retry gRPC calls that fail with the status code `Unavailable` (can be defined in the `RetryableStatusCodes`)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
List<ChannelOption> channelOptions = new List<ChannelOption>
{
    new ChannelOption("grpc.initial_reconnect_backoff_ms", 1000),
    new ChannelOption("grpc.max_reconnect_backoff_ms", 1000)
};

channel = new Channel(host, port, ChannelCredentials.Insecure, channelOptions);
client = new Commands.CommandsClient(channel);
```